# Python fails to load dll when is run from cmd or powershell or cygwin but works in Git Bash

Tags: python, dll, cmd, ctypes, mingw-w64

I have a 64 bit dll "tdjson.dll" (telegram tdlib) which I want to use from my python project.
The problem is that python fails to import DLL when I run my code from CMD or PowerShell or Cygwin or any other terminal but Git Bash. The only way to run my code is to execute it from Git Bash terminal coming with Git for Windows.

Here are logs from both Mingw64 and CMD:

```
usrname@pcname MINGW64 /e/projects/tele (master)
$ where python
C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe

usrname@pcname MINGW64 /e/projects/tele (master)
$ python -i
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> CDLL("tdjson.dll")
<CDLL 'tdjson.dll', handle 7ffd19a70000 at 0x2939d19b0b8>
>>>
```

---

```
E:\projects\tele>where python
C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe

E:\projects\tele>python -i
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> CDLL("tdjson.dll")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>>>
```

Comment: In which directory does `"tdjson.dll"` exist?

Comment: @lit it's in the current directory (e:\projects\tele\tdjson.dll)

Comment: *tdjson.dll* depends on other *.dll*s (besides *Windows* ones). The problem is that in your *Win* environment, you also have the *32 bit* versions of (at least one of the) dependencies in your *%PATH%* (before the *64 bit* ones).